# Does timing matter when adding coconut oil to rice to reduce calories?

Tags: food-chemistry

I ran in to a rice [recipe](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2015/03/25/scientists-have-figured-out-a-simple-way-to-cook-rice-that-dramatically-cuts-the-calories/) that can reduce carbs and calories when adding coconut oil. The exact direction is that you 1. boil water 2. add coconut oil 3. cook rice as you normally would.

My question is, does it change the end result (end with less calories) if I add water, coconut oil, and rice at the same time?

Comment: I see no way that adding oil (a high-caloric substance) would _reduce_ calories at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about chemistry. It is more suited to cooking.SE.

Comment: @bon are you able to just migrate it to cooking? I don't know how it's done, but this seems like the appropriate time to do so. They are well suited to tease apart nutritional claims from facts. My 2 cents - the only thing it does is sell more coconut oil.

Comment: @Michelle, the question of nutritional calories is more complicated than just chemistry - it depends on the biology of the thing that eats as well. While some people call that chemistry also, it's not a good question here, at least the way you wrote it.

Comment: @uhoh Migration can only be done by mods unless migration paths has been set up. They're not.